# choral chorale choir chorus What's the difference between the four words?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, difference, synonyms

choral chorale choir chorus

They're similar in meaning, pronunciation, and spelling.

What's the difference?

For example, in the game "Heroes of Might and Magic 7", there're "Choral of Believers" and the counterpart "Choir of Despair".

resources:

Choir of Despair: https://mightandmagic.fandom.com/wiki/Necropolis_(H7)

Choral of Believers in H7: https://mightandmagic.fandom.com/wiki/Haven_(H7)

in H6: https://mightandmagic.fandom.com/wiki/Haven_(H6)

---

I've checked a few dictionaries and other resources.

Take the nominal meaning of "a group of people singing together" for example:

choral: both H6 and H7 used it this way.

chorale: α "Collins COBUILD" definition 2. β "A choir (; also known as a quire, chorale or chorus) is a musical ensemble of singers." (https://www.askdifference.com/choir-vs-chorale/)

choir: every dictionaries that I've checked.

chorus: every dictionaries that I've checked, and those dictionaries say in chorus people not only sing but also dance.

By the way, "chorus" has a definition of "a part of a song which is repeated after each verse", which the other three don't share.

What I'm asking is the differences between the similarities, which mainly focus on "a group of people singing together".

For instance, it seems that both "chorale" and "choir" can refer to the place/room where people sing together?

If you like, you can also talk about the meaning of "a religious song".

Comment: Have you checked dictionary definitions? What did you find?

Comment: The most common spelling is ***choral*** for "a sacred choral song". The extra 'e' is sometimes used there, but (mainly in the US) it's also often used to mean *a group of singers who sing principally choral music*. Specifically, used in the ***names of choirs***, as *The Paul Hill Chorale, a 165-voice amateur ensemble*. You can read up for yourself all about stuff like the ***chorus*** in ancient Greek theatre. Modern use in "mock-archaic" game or TV series contexts doesn't necessarily reflect anything more than what the ***scriptwriters*** think carries the right kind of "allusions".

Comment: _Choral_ as an adjective means _performed by, or associated with, choirs_ , and is pronounced with the stress on the first syllable. As a noun it's usually spelled with a final 'e' and is pronounced with the stress on the second syllable, meaning either a choir or a certain type of sacred music.

Comment: @KateBunting At first, I also though choral was an adjective, until I saw "Choral of Believers" in both Heroes 6 (https://mightandmagic.fandom.com/wiki/Haven_(H6)) and Heroes 7.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I upgraded my question.

Comment: A group of choral singers is usually called a choir, but choirs sometimes choose a name using the word _chorus_  or _chorale_ instead. The only chorus that dances is the _chorus line_ in a stage musical. I don't know why the computer game people have used the term _choral_ as a noun. The part of a church where the choir sit is sometimes called _the choir_, but otherwise these words don't refer to places. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chorale) is a definition of _chorale_ as religious music.

Comment: Most dictionaries don't show "choral" as a noun, but I've seen it somewhere before, and Wiktionary does show it as a variant of "chorale", with the same second-syllable emphasis. Also, the French spelling of "' chorale" is "choral".